# Solve Do-while loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double x = 1;
double y = 2;
int i = 1;
do
{
y /= 2.0;
x+= y;
++i;
cout << i;
}

while (x < 2.4);
}
```

I thought the output would be 2, but that is not correct. Can someone explain why?

Comment: The loop executes more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the condition which controls whether or not your loop will execute again. At the end of the first loop, the value of `x` is 2.0. Since this is less than 2.4, the loop runs a second time. In total that means `i` is incremented twice raising it to 3.